# How do I set up a visual margin in vi when colorcolumn is not supported?

Tags: vim, margin

I am working on vim 7.0 and the colorcolumn is not supported.

I am looking for a visual vertical colored margin to manage long lines. Are there any available options to achieve it?  I have a mac and colorcolumn works great.

I have found some similar ones but that is not what I want.  Below lines added to .vimrc achieves something similar but it does not give me a visual colored margin.  It basically points out anything greater than a certain character range.

```
highlight OverLength ctermbg=red ctermfg=white guibg=#592929
match OverLength /\%81v.\+/
```

Ideally this could be achieved with a later version like this

```
set colorcolumn=79
```

This screenshot shows what I am looking for.

[image]

Comment: No. [This trick](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip810) is old: it was the de facto (and only) way to do it in Vim prior to the introduction of `colorcolumn`.

Answer (score 1):

With the `:highlight` trick you included and that romainl linked to, you can highlight the character(s) that are longer than desired, but that won't get you a continuous line (shorter lines will interrupt), only `'colorcolumn'` can achieve that.

The only other clumsy workaround I can think of is setting the window width to your desired width, so you notice overlong lines when the window starts scrolling horizontally.

Vim 7.0 is from 2006; you're missing out on much more; I really hope you can upgrade, that's the real solution.